# Проверка элементов двух массивов

Tags: python, массивы

У меня есть два условных массива.

**Первый:**
`['Комедия', 'Драма', 'Хоррор']`

**Второй:**
`['Комедия', 'Сверхъестественное', 'Драма', 'Романтика', 'Школа']`

Мне нужна проверка, есть ли во втором массиве один из элементов первого *(в примере их два, но достаточно и одного)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить, что пересечение множеств не пусто:

```
janres1 = ['Комедия', 'Драма', 'Хоррор']
janres2 = ['Комедия', 'Сверхъестественное', 'Драма', 'Романтика', 'Школа']
print(set(janres1) & set(janres2))
print(bool(set(janres1) & set(janres2)))
```

Вывод:

```
{'Комедия', 'Драма'}
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Подробный вариант решения:

```
list_1 = ['Комедия', 'Драма', 'Хоррор']

list_2 = ['Комедия', 'Сверхъестественное', 'Драма', 'Романтика', 'Школа']

flag = False

for val in list_1:
    if val in list_2:
        flag = True
        break
if flag:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```